# Symfony 2 routing with defaults values

Tags: symfony, routes, defaults

i've a problem with my routing.yml in Symfony. 
When i put a defaults value it's return me and empty value. I dont knopw why he does it.
I do it like Symfony's doc but problem persist
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

```
lapille_plateform_homepage:
        path:     /{page}
        defaults: 
            _controller: LAPILLEPlateformBundle:Advert:index
            page: 1
        requirements:
            page: \d*
```

and my error it's an empty variable like that
[Symfony error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83kPJ.png)

Thanks a lot for you help.

Alexandre

SOLVED

Change requirements

```
requirements:
    page: \d*
```

by

```
requirements:
    page: \d+
```

thx all

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
lapille_plateform_homepage:
        path:     /{page}
        defaults: { _controller: LAPILLEPlateformBundle:Advert:index, page: 1}
        requirements:
            page: \d*
```

Comment: Why would the same code formatted slightly differently make a difference?

Comment: Ok it's solved... i change my requirements

page: \d*

by 

page: \d+

tanks you all